# What's the right way to pass a var to a Python unittest TestCase and/or TestSuite?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I need to run a Python unittest test suite against multiple REST backend resources so I need to pass in a Resource object to the test suite and individual testcases.

Is setting a global var the right way to do this, or is there a better way?

resource = Resource('http://example.com')

```
class RestTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.resource = resource

def suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(RestTestCase))
    return suite

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(defaultTest='suite')
```

Comment: If the answer below was satisfactory, please mark it as accepted.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the example of the how the standard library writes its own unittests. Put the resource in a class variable and use inheritance to test the various resources:

```
class RestTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    resource = Resource('http://example.com')

    def sometest(self):
        r = self.resource
        ...
        self.assertEqual(expectedresult, actualresult)

class SomeOtherRestTestCase(RestTestCase):
    resource = Resource('http://someother.example.com')

class YetAnotherRestTestCase(RestTestCase):
    resource = Resource('http://yetanother.example.com')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: What if you don't want the tests to run from the base class? i.e. in this example, if you wanted RestTestCase to be abstract.

Comment: Set resource to None in the base class and raise a NotImplementedError in any of the base-class methods that must be overridden by the subclass.